# Pass NUnit Test Category through command line

Tags: nunit, dotnet-test

I am trying to use NUnit [Category](https://docs.nunit.org/2.4.8/category.html) attribute to run a set of tests at a time.

But how to pass the category as an argument while running the tests from command line?

Tried multiple things, but none of them seems to be working:

```
dotnet test /include Category=AfterReboot mytests.dll --> Error:The argument /include is invalid. Please use the /help option to check the list of valid arguments.

dotnet test --filter Category=AfterReboot mytests.dll --> Error:The argument --filer:category=AfterReboot is invalid. Please use the /help option to check the list of valid arguments.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Belor worked.

dotnet test  --filter  "Category = AfterReboot" mytests.dll

Answer (score 0):

The correct filter is TestCategory with dotnet 6.0.400

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=CategoryA
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.

Comment: Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers ? Are you serious? the previous answer just does not work. The correct filter is --filter TestCategory, just that.